# operators && and || doesn't stack

Tags: php, operators

i have little trouble with operators in this code. I need to at least one of the 'and' pair to be true to continue. In the example it should say true but it doesn't. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$i = 1;
$e = 5;
$c = 3;
$d = 4;
$b = 6;
$a = 7;

if ( (i==1 && e==4) || (a==7 && b==5) || (c==3 && d==4) ){
echo 'true';
}else{
echo 'false';
}
```

Comment: Add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the beginning. Then you'll find out what the problem is.

Comment: Wow guys you are pretty fast :). and sorry for this stupid question i am an idiot and dindn't notice this stupid mistake. thx again guys :)

Comment: @Freezaman Haha, no problem at all - it happens to _all_ of us once in a while. I'll close this out for you.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the problem was a lack of caffeine. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$` for variable referencing.

```
if ( ($i==1 && $e==4) || ($a==7 && $b==5) || ($c==3 && $d==4) ){
      ^        ^          ^        ^          ^        ^
```

It might be a facepalm moment, but it happens sometimes ;)

In such cases what would **really** help is to turn on PHP error reporting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if ( ($i==1 && $e==4) || ($a==7 && $b==5) || ($c==3 && $d==4) ){
echo 'true';
}else{
echo 'false';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( ($i==1 && $e==4) || ($a==7 && $b==5) || ($c==3 && $d==4) ){
    echo 'true';
}else{
    echo 'false';
}
```

You forgot the `$`